# How can i print 'Generating Password' including a function on the same line in Python?

Tags: python

**What i am tring to do**

I am trying to print 'Generating Password' with a moving ellipsis afterwards. Something like this:

```
Generating Password . (then wait a bit) . (then wait a bit) . (then wait a bit) .
```

So it has three stages:

```
Generating Password .
Generating Password ..
Generating Password ...
```

But i would like these all to be on one single line. How can i do this?

**My function so far:**

```
def moving_ellipsis(num=3, time_delay=1):
        for i in range(num):
            print('Generating Password')  
            print('.', end='', flush=True) # I want this to be on the end of the above print ^
            time.sleep(time_delay)
```

Comment: Read the docs on [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) carefully. Hint: ``end=...`` defaults to ``\n``.

Comment: oh i see... thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close to getting it.

```
def moving_ellipsis(num=3, time_delay=1):
    print('Generating Password', end="")

    for i in range(num):
        print('.', end='', flush=True) # I want this to be on the end of the above print ^
        time.sleep(time_delay)
```

Notice how I moved the `print` **outside** the loop and set `end=""`.

Comment: yes that makes sense. thanks for the answer :D